# Angular : Unable to build application

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on an angular6 app using asp.net core 2.1.

On building the project using `ng build --prod` I am getting below errors but if I run the project its working perfectly :

> ERROR in Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'replace' of undefined
>
> - at normalizeBackSlashDirection (D:\New    Loc\Angular6_Core_2\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:15:17)
> - at new RequestShortener (D:\New    Loc\Angular6_Core_2\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:25:15)
> - at new Compiler (D:\New    Loc\Angular6_Core_2\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:136:27)
> - at Compiler.createChildCompiler (D:\New    Loc\Angular6_Core_2\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:371:25)
> - at Compilation.createChildCompiler (D:\New    Loc\Angular6_Core_2\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1851:24)
> - at Object.pitch (D:\New    Loc\Angular6_Core_2\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\ClientApp\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:78:43)

**Edit :**

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "WebApplication1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.9",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^9.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^13.0.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.8.0",
    "primeng": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.24.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should have a binding for  a field `replace` in one of your html templates, and the property is not there in the component.

Comment: No its not there in any of pages, I searched with "replace"

Comment: maybe you-re linking a non existing css or other style file

Comment: run `npm i` and try again

Comment: @LahiruChandima this is a webpack issue, as stated in the trace. So a library issue, not a project one.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, if this would be the issue how can I run the app using ng serve..

Comment: same reullt @trichetriche..

Comment: Then consider updating your libraries to their latest major and minor versions, or even consider leaving an issue on webpack's repository.

Comment: each and every package is updated..

Comment: This is a brand new project or you migrated an old project to a new version of your dependencies ?

Comment: its new one i created a new project today, installed all packages..

Comment: @SunilKumar https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/186  check this

Comment: @SunilKumar you could also post your webpack configuration that would help to relate more

Comment: @KeshanNageswaran are you asking about webpack.prod.js?

Answer (score -1):

**Try this :**

```
ng build --env=prod
```

Comment: Unknown option: '--env'

Comment: Angular 6 is `--configuration=prod`, but you can shorten to `--prod`